# Load CSS with <link> tag and HTMLWebpackPlugin

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-style-loader, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-file-loader

I want to use `<link>`  (it's important - I don't want to use a `<style>`) tag to load external CSS (from npm dependencies). I'm using HTMLWebpackPlugin.

I have tried something like this:

```
<link href="style!css!file!~@internal-scope/package-name/dist/some.css" rel="stylesheet" id="important-id">
```

But Webpack keeps replacing the href with `[Object object]`. Which I assume is caused that Webpack is trying to use esModules? But when I'm turning off esModule with `...!file?esModule=false!...` I'm getting errors like:

```
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in (...)
```

Also I tried to use only `file-loader` (as @felixmosh proposed) - still the same issue as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case chaining `css-loader` & `style-loader` are not relevant.

`css-loader` loads css and passes down an **object** with a selectors map + the css string.
`style-loader` injects the css and returns the same **object**.

Therefore, you get `[Object object]`.

Try to use only `file-loader`, which returns a **string** with the path to a static file, and emits the file to `outputPath`.

```html
<link href="!!file?esModule=false!~@internal-scope/package-name/dist/some.css" rel="stylesheet" id="important-id">
// ---------^ these !! are important to prevent from running rest of the loaders which are suitable from your config.
```

BTW, why you are trying to inject it directly in the template and not import it in `js` and let `HTMLWebpack` do it's thing? (it is by default injects `link` tag to **emitted** css files)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention it, that I tried this too. Again issue with esModule and this strange error mentioned by me.

Comment: Try to specify the options inline, and mark that this is the only loader which should be run (by prefix of !!)

Comment: I tried that too.
Ad. BTW: Default tag is <script>, but style-loader has parametr injectType . Hmm I guess I can try one more time that solution. The ID in link tag is really important for me.

Comment: You can inject this `id` by using custom template  and modifying the relevant css in `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags`.
Do you have any "demo" repo which I can play with?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's a closed project... :/
style-loader allows also to set custom attributes for a tag (`attributes` property). I will play with this style-loader and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me: `require('!!style-loader?{"injectType":"linkTag","attributes":{"id":"important-id"},"esModule":false}!file-loader?esModule=false!@internal-scope/package/dist/file.css')`. But it's so strange that this does not work with `file-loader` only in HTML. Maybe bug in HTMLWebpackPlugin?

Comment: I've made small repo which your idea does works properly.
https://github.com/felixmosh/test-inject-attr

Comment: I see that it's working, but I cannot figure out why it's not working in my repo... I even updated dependencies to have the same version as you... But nevermind. I'm marking your response as an answer! Thank you!